# la validación de un formulario php en Laravel no se ejecuta correctamente antes de enviar los datos a la BD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy terminando un formulario en el que necesito subir una *FOTO*, y un campo *SORT* para establece el orden, y no consigo hacer llegar el error de que la foto ya existe antes de pasar a la **BD** y no me salga este típico mensaje, os dejo el código que estoy ejecutando.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request,[
        'url'=>'required|unique:carousels|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
        'sort'=>'required|unique:carousels'
    ]);

    $fileName = null;
    if (request()->hasFile('url')) {
        $file = request()->file('url');
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('./public/images/', $fileName);
    }

    $carousel=Carousel::create([
        'sort' => request()->get('sort'),
        'url' => $fileName
    ]);

    return Redirect::to('carousel')->with('status_create', "Se ha creado correctamente la nueva $carousel->url");
}
```

Y este es el error que me sale y yo quiero que el error me salga en el propio formulario sin llegar a esto.

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000) SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'arqueologia1.jpg' for key 'url' (SQL: insert into `carousels`
>   (`sort`, `url`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (66,
>   arqueologia1.jpg, 2019-08-28 15:30:53, 2019-08-28 15:30:53)) Previous
>   exceptions SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry 'arqueologia1.jpg' for key 'url' (23000)

A ver si podéis ayudarme en que estoy fallando que no doy con la tecla, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: lo edito entonces gracias por el comentario

Comment: si lo que quieres validar que la foto ya existe, validar que el nombre sea único no te va a servir, ya que un usuario podría subir la misma foto cambiándole el nombre. entonces, ¿que es lo que quieres lograr? ¿no tener fotos duplicadas o que dos fotos no tengan el mismo nombre?

Comment: lo único que quiero es no tener dos fotos aunque sean distintas fotos, pero no con el mismo nombre. Aunque si existe tb alguna forma de invalidar tb que se pueda subir dos veces la misma fotos tb me serviría de ayuda pero claro si le cambias el nombre imagino que se lo salta la validación.

Comment: si es solo un tema de nombres de los archivos, y no necesitas que el nombre del archivo sea "amigable" para la lectura de un humano, podés usar [`store()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads) en vez de `move()`, el cual "generará una ID única para servir como el nombre del archivo.". También puedes concatenarle un timestamp al nombre original, con [uniqid()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php) por ejemplo. Te servirían nombres así?:  `YrErEDghdutdysx5DfcfD.jpg` o `12345677arqueologia.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas validar que el nombre de la foto no se encuentre registrado en tu tabla, intenta con este cambio a la regla "unique":

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'url'=>'required|unique:carousels,url|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
    'sort'=>'required|unique:carousels,sort'
]);
```

En el ejemplo que proporcionas no indicas el segundo parámetro y por default la validación intenta aplicarla sobre la columna "name" (aunque esta no exista en tu tabla).
El segundo parámetro indica el nombre de la columna sobre el cual hará la comparación.

Si requieres más detalle, puedes ver la definición completa aquí: [laravel unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique)